# How to migrate spring project from BoneCP to HikariCP for postgressql databse?

Tags: java, postgresql, migration, hikaricp, bonecp

These are the beans I have created and trying to use Hikari in my project but getting the errors.

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean Configuration method:

```
@Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.xyz.entitiy" });
      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
      return em;
   }
```

DataSource configuration method:

```
 @Bean
     public DataSource dataSource() {
         HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(); config.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
         config.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc");
         config.setUsername("abc");
         config.setPassword("abc");

         return new HikariDataSource(config);
     }
```

PlatformTransactionManager configuration method:

```
@Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
      return transactionManager;
   }
```

PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor configuration method:

```
@Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
      return transactionManager;
   }
```

Properties configuration method:

```
  private  Properties additionalProperties() {
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "");
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
      return properties;
   }
```

I'm trying to migrate from BoneCP to HikariCP for PostgreSQL. But facing this issue:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.xyz.ets.persistence.config.PersistenceContext: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.xyz.ets.persistence.config.PersistenceContext: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.xyz.ets.persistence.config.PersistenceContext: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.
Sep 25, 2018 12:47:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
```

pom.file dependency using:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i have bulked together all the errors and in the same place.

Comment: thanks, I was able to solve the issue. It was happening because of multiple dependency conflict.